# Barplot savefig() returning an AttributeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm converting an iPython notebook to a python script, just trying to output the results of a couple Seaborn plots as png files. Code:

```
import seaborn as sns

...

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x=range(1,11), y=[ (x/nrows)*100 for x in addr_pop ], palette="Blues_d")
ax.savefig("html/addr_depth.png")
```

Don't worry about the variables, they're populated as expected, and I get a great-looking chart in iPyNB. Running the code within a script, however, yields `RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable`.

Following another thread, I modified the code, putting this at the top of the script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

And tried again. This time, it doesn't seem like the `savefig()` method is available for the plot at all:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

All the results searching out this error are related to pandas and a plot that is already being displayed. I'm just trying to get Seaborn to output the fig to a file, ideally without displaying it at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912958/matplotlib-subplots-figure-savefig-wont-output-pdf-nonetype-error

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing

```
ax.savefig('file.png')
```

to

```
ax.figure.savefig('file.png')
```

I guess accessing the figure directly is one way to get to the `savefig()` method for the barplot.

@WoodChopper also has a working solution, but it requires another import statement, and utilizing pyplot's `savefig()` directly.

Either solution does require setting `matplotlib.use('Agg')` to get around the DISPLAY variable error. As the [referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) noted, this has to be set before importing other matplotlib libraries.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you should import pyplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig()
```

Comment: OK, that does work. I'm a little confused as to why, but this does solve the issue. I also found a way to do it without the need to import pyplot separately. Changing `ax.savefig()` to `ax.figure.savefig()` has the same effect, and seems a little cleaner. Maybe someone can comment and shed some light on the differences.

Comment: You could read up on the object-oriented interface, for example [this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut2.html) is very clear. It should help you see how these things all fit together.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I have to use `.figure.`